# Can anyone explain the internal processing of this code that why it is generating output as [<__main__.Movie object at 0x000002DAE7122FD0>]

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Can anyone explain below output:

```
[<__main__.Movie object at 0x000002DAE7122FD0>]
```

As in the while loop i am creating multiple objects and storing in a list, when i am printing the list i am getting output as `[<__main__.Movie object at 0x000002DAE7122FD0>]`.

As,
`m = Movie(title,actor,actress)` #object created and the reference variable is m, that in the next step getting appended in a list.

```
class Movie:

 def __init__(self,title,actor,actress):
  self.title = title
  self.actor = actor
  self.actress = actress

 def info(self):
  print("Movie: ",self.title)
  print("Actor: ",self.actor)
  print("Actress: ",self.actress)

while True:
 title = input("Enter movie name")
 actor = input("Enter actor name")
 actress = input("Enter actress name")
 movieobj = Movie(title,actor,actress)
 list_of_movies = []
 list_of_movies.append(movieobj)
 option = input("Do you want to add more movies? [yes/no]")
 if option.lower() == 'no':
  break

print(list_of_movies)
```

Comment: What are you expecting instead? You made a list of movies, and `<__main__.Movie object ...>` is the representation of a Movie object.

Comment: You're emptying the list each time through the loop with `list_of_movies = []`. You should do that *before* the loop.

Comment: This is a common beginner mistake, I will never understand it.

Answer (score 2):

`[<__main__.Movie object at 0x000002DAE7122FD0>]` is showing that you have a list with one reference to a Movie object in it (along with the [`id` of the object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), which is its memory address in cPython, which you are likely using)

```py
[<__main__.Movie object at 0x000002DAE7122FD0>]
||                         |id(obj)         |||
||                                           ||
||one Movie object defined in __main__       ||
|                                             |
|this is a list                               |
```

Your `Movie` class needs a [`__repr__` method to *represent* itself](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) as a string

```py
>>> class X(): pass
...
>>> [X()]
[<__main__.X object at 0x107b9f130>]
>>> class Y():
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return "string about Y object custom whatever"
...
>>> [Y()]
[string about Y object custom whatever]
```

As [**@Barmar** notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66392527/can-anyone-explain-the-internal-processing-of-this-code-that-why-it-is-generatin/66392609#comment117375346_66392527), you also re-create the list each loop iteration, which is why you only find a single entry in the list (rather than the collection growing with each user input cycle, which is probably what you intended). You can move the list assignment ( `= []`) out of the loop body to fix this!

```py
while True:
    lst = []  # creates a new list each loop
    # lst refers to the new, empty list
```

```py
lst = []  # new list created prior to loop
while True:
    # lst refers to the list outside the loop
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question of why the list only has one element even though he entered multiple movies?

Comment: I think really they have two questions, hopefully this answers both now!

Answer (score 0):

Your list contains an object you can get specific attributes of it my using movieobj.attribute but appending the object will provide you with the memory location of it

Comment: I don't think that's his question. The question seems to be why the list only has one element even though he enters multiple movies. It's because the list initialization is misplaced.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, declared an empty list in the while loop and everytime the loop runs the list becomes empty, that's the result i am getting only 1 object when i printing that list. Thanks.

Comment: Did you see my earlier comment? You have the line `list_of_movies = []` in the wrong place. Just fix that.

Comment: Yeah i saw your comment and placed the declaration of list outside the while loop. Now i can see a list of multiple object each having a unique id in output. Thanks @Barmar